# How I can get return from PHP to Ionic Controller?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my code. Please help me return id in PHP condition to angular controller. I get undefined in console log. This is my code. Its wrong and bad code? Thanks

My Ionic controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.LoginUser = function(info){
    console.log(info.username, info.password);
    var xhr = $http.post('http://pvcm.com/api/tambah_user.php', info);
    console.log(xhr);
  };
})
```

My PHP

```
    if(isset($data)){
        $host = "";
        $username_database = "";
        $pass_database = "";
        $database = "";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username_database, $pass_database, $database);

        $sql_petugas = "SELECT * FROM petugas WHERE id_petugas = '$data->username' AND password_petugas = '$data->password'";
        $sql_masyarakat = "SELECT * FROM masyarakat WHERE id_masyarakat = '$data->username' AND password_masyarakat = '$data->password'";
        //$hasil = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $hasil_petugas=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_petugas); 
        $hasil_masyarakat=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_masyarakat); 

        $count_petugas = mysqli_num_rows($hasil_petugas);
        $count_masyarakat = mysqli_num_rows($hasil_masyarakat);

        if($count_petugas > 0){
            return json_decode('id'=>100);
        }else if($count_masyarakat > 0){
            return "masyarakat ketemu";
        }

        $qry = $conn->query($sql);
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Ionic side you are missing the promise. The `$http` returns a promise, not the data itself, that means that you have to use another function to get the data. Like this:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.LoginUser = function(info){
    console.log(info.username, info.password);
    var xhr;
    $http.post('http://pvcm.com/api/tambah_user.php', info)
         .then(function(phpData){
                    xhr = phpData;
          })
         .catch(function(error){
                    xhr = error;
          });
    console.log(xhr);
  };
})
```

Here, the function inside `.then()` executes if the request was successfull and gets the data in the `phpData` parameter, and the `.catch()` excecutes if the request was an error (404, 500, etc).

In the PHP code I think you have to print the result instead of returning it. Like `echo json_decode('id'=>100);`

Comment: Hello Hiraqui, thanks for your help. I still have an error like this : http://prntscr.com/duqh6g

Note : 3 is my id and asd is my password in database

Comment: Oh that's because your php is protecting you from ajax request coming from external sources. You can by pass it adding in your php code a header like this:  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  The * allows any origin, so be careful.

Comment: Yes, I added it but my program still have that error console. Why?